# Return a pointer from a function

Tags: c

Is the following syntax correct for returning a pointer from a function?

```
bmpfile_t*
bmp_create_from_file(const char *filename, bmpfile_t *bmp)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    bmp_get_header_from_file(fp, bmp);
    bmp_get_dib_from_file(fp, bmp);
    bmp_get_pixels_from_file(fp, bmp);
    fclose(fp);

    return &bmp;
}
```

Comment: Hint - it doesn't compile without warnings.  What does that make you think?

Comment: I am passing a pointer to a bmpfile_t to many functions and just wanted to rule out the possibility that I am doing it wrong.

Comment: `bmp` is a local automatic variable initialized to a value passed in by the function caller. `&bmp` results in the address of that local variable. You should never return the address of a local automatic variable from a function.

Comment: Why do you want to return a value at all? The pointer isn't being modified.

Comment: Right, and it would make more sense for the function to not take a bmpfile_t* as argument in the first place, but to create it and then return it, methinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bmp` already has type `bmpfile_t *`, which is what you want to return. So just `return bmp`.

Edit: What you are currently trying to return, `&bmp`, is the address of a `bmpfile_t *`, and hence has type `bmpfile_t **`, a pointer to a pointer. Furthermore, as others have pointed out, `&bmp` would be the address of `bmp`, which is a local stack variable in your function. This will be popped when you return from the function, and hence that pointer will point at something useless. So not only are you returning something with the wrong type, you are also returning something dangerous. So just `return bmp`.

Comment: I've been so bold as to edit out the "clearly" and have given you a +1.